# Using a Javascript lightbox effect for multiple links on same page

Tags: javascript, arrays, lightbox

I am trying to code a simple lightbox effect that I can use for multiple images on the same page. (Click a link, image shows up on with the website opaque in the background.) I found a nice little Javascript, but it only works for a single image on the page. I know my HTML and CSS, but I'm struggling to find a clean, simple solution for what *should be* a simple function. (Unfortunately, I'm not a Javascript coder, but I usually can modify scripts I find to work for what I need...this is just beyond my scope!)

Here's my Javascript:

```
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    if (!e){
        e = event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        lightbox_close();
    }
}
function lightbox_open(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.querySelector('.light').style.display='block';
    document.querySelector('.fade').style.display='block';  
}
function lightbox_close(){
    document.querySelector('.light').style.display='none';
    document.querySelector('.fade').style.display='none';
}
```

After doing some research, and I changed the original `getElementById` to `querySelector` since I need to apply this to multiple images. But I'm thinking I need to switch back to ID, and possibly use numbered IDs to differentiate my images. But I'm not sure how to use one function for multiple instances.

My CSS is:

```
.fade {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.light {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -100px;                 
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

I haven't perfected the CSS, but I'm not worried about it at this point. I just need to get the Javascript working first.

And my HTML is something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open();">Photo 1</a>
<div class="light">
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close();"><img src="portfolio/print/hwtc/bcard-MUC.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div class="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>

<br />

<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open();">Photo 2</a>
<div class="light">
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close();"><img src="portfolio/print/hwtc/bcard-CUN.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div class="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
```

Like I said, this isn't my Javascript; I'm just in over my head trying to modify it for my needs. There's got to be a simple way to achieve this, but I don't know enough Javascript coding to do it myself. I probably need an array or something?? Can someone please help a girl out?? =) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have other purposes to deal with numbered IDs with images , you don't need to switch them back , A little revise , I hope this could help you
, demo : http://codepen.io/Carr1005/pen/PzBgom

```
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    if (!e){
        e = event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        lightbox_close();
    }
}

function lightbox_open(index){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.querySelectorAll('.light')[index].style.display='block';
    document.querySelectorAll('.fade')[index].style.display='block';  
}

function lightbox_close(index){
    document.querySelectorAll('.light')[index].style.display='none';
    document.querySelectorAll('.fade')[index].style.display='none';
}
```

and html part

```
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open(0);">Photo 1</a>
<div class="light">
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close(0);"><img src="portfolio/print/hwtc/bcard-MUC.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div class="fade" onClick="lightbox_close(0);"></div>

<br />

<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open(1);">Photo 2</a>
<div class="light">
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_close(1);"><img src="portfolio/print/hwtc/bcard-CUN.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
<div class="fade" onClick="lightbox_close(1);"></div>
```

============================================================

There is a saying that using onClick() is a bad practice , [here is why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)

I think in some situations is not that bad to use onclick() , but if you wanna
go in this direction , here is another example , and maybe it's a chance to look into more javascript 
http://codepen.io/Carr1005/pen/wWxVYE?editors=1111